# Jquery load content into ajax container and alert when is fully complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

Hi I have a problem with this. I'm loading a new page into my DOM, in a container, and the alert is displayed before the elements like images or videos are loaded.

```
height : function (){ 
    var newHeight = $('#primary').height();   
    var el = $('.show-container');
    el.css({'height': newHeight + 'px'});    
},

loading : function(page){           
    var self= this;
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); 
    $('#ajax-inserted1').load(page, function(){   
         $('#remove').removeClass('to-screen').addClass('to-left');
         $(this).removeClass('to-right, to-left');
         $(this).addClass('to-screen');

         self.height();
     });
 },
```

Is it possible to wait until everything has fully loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `$.get(url, data, success)` which is nearly the same except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function.

Then set the ASYNC property to false.

This is not recommended since AJAX was made for async calls.  But that is one way to do it.

**It is best to use the `complete` callback that is in the third parameter of .load() to do anything after the AJAX call.**

`.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`

**Ex**

```
$('#ajax-container').load(page, function(){   
    var height = $(this).height();
    alert(height);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael but the last one: Is what i'm doing or i'm wrong?

Comment: Yes you are.  What is the page variable set to?

Comment: to the_permalink() the wordpress function

Comment: I'm loading the page, but I want to get the height of the div that contains the page but I get the height before all the content is fully loaded.

Comment: Yes because you need to get the height in the success call back...Ill update my answer for an example

Comment: OK that will be great

Comment: Please add that to your Question